# What's the best way to upgrade Spring 2.5.6 to Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am supporting a legacy Spring 2.5.6 application where it is getting increasingly difficult to add new features. How can I upgrade this to Spring Boot? Anyone has had any success?

Comment: First: Upgrade (successfully) to Spring >= V4 (good luck!), then adding spring boot is peanuts ;)

Comment: Not that easy to find, but voila: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-3.x and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-4.x

Answer (score 0):

There is a migration guide published by baeldung, I hope this helps. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration